# MySQL is not letting me add a FROM command after my UPDATE and SET commands

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to run a query that matches rows from two tables based on a few WHERE conditions and then appends the link from table 2 onto a new column in table 1 for those matched rows.
I run

```
UPDATE
    maxpreps_player_stats AS mp
SET pbr_link = pbr.plink
FROM pbr_urls AS pbr
WHERE (LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.name, 1, 3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.fullname, 1, 3))
    AND LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.name, -3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.fullname, -3))
    AND LOWER(pbr.state) = LOWER(mp.team_state)
    AND LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.school, 1, 3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.hsname, 1, 3))
    AND (pbr.class = mp.grad_lower_bound OR pbr.class = mp.grad_upper_bound));
```

but it gives me the error that "FROM" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Comment: Read the manual for syntax/functionality you are using. This is also a faq. Research before considering posting. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is not supported in MySql.
You can do it with a join like this:

```
UPDATE maxpreps_player_stats AS mp
INNER JOIN pbr_urls AS pbr
ON      LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.name, 1, 3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.fullname, 1, 3))
    AND LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.name, -3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.fullname, -3))
    AND LOWER(pbr.state) = LOWER(mp.team_state)
    AND LOWER(SUBSTRING(pbr.school, 1, 3)) = LOWER(SUBSTRING(mp.hsname, 1, 3))
    AND (pbr.class = mp.grad_lower_bound OR pbr.class = mp.grad_upper_bound)
SET mp.pbr_link = pbr.plink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use FROM in UPDATE query